# how to mock dynamic child component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

```
    private async loadPageNotFoundContainer() {
    this.productErrorPageTemplate?.clear();
    const { ProductErrorPageContainer } = await import(
      '../../lazy/product-error-page/product-error-page.container'
    );
this.productErrorPageTemplate.createComponent(this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ProductErrorPageContainer));
  }
```

here you can see i want loadPageNotFoundContainer load the mock component instead of ProductErrorPageContainer so can simplify the test.
and loadPageNotFoundContainer is private function

Comment: You can't mock `private` members without having typescript complain. The one hand, if a function is meant to be tested, it should not be private semantically. However, there are lots of reasons not to use `private` in typescript specifically. It's misleading, doesn't have any run time enforcement, and has completely different semantics from ES private fields, causing confusion. Personally, I think the `private` keyword in TS is one of the languages worst and few mistakes, although the `abstract` keyword is far worse.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, I do the dynamic import in its own method to have full control of the promise and I can spy on it and return whatever I would like.

```
private async loadPageNotFoundContainer() {
    this.productErrorPageTemplate?.clear();
    const ProductErrorPageContainer = await this.getProductErrorPageContainer();
this.productErrorPageTemplate.createComponent(this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ProductErrorPageContainer));
  }

private async getProductErrorPageContainer() {
  const { ProductErrorPageContainer } = await import(
      '../../lazy/product-error-page/product-error-page.container'
    );
  return ProductErrorPageContainer;
}
```

Then in the test, you can do:

```
spyOn(component as any, 'getProductErrorPageContainer').and.resolveTo(/* Whatever value you wish */);
```

You can still spy on private methods although you have to use `as any`.

Answer (score 0):

[`ng-mocks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) mocks such a component, you should simply configure `TestBed` in that way with help of [`MockBuilder`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder):

```js
beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(
  YourComponent,
  [ItsModule, ProductErrorPageContainer],
));
```

After that `createComponent` will receive a mock of `ProductErrorPageContainer`.